# How to show different pages for different users

Tags: users

I am new with wordpress en I try to build a website for soccer teams. this is what I like to have:

team name (Arsenal) 1 role: player1 can see the following pages (Test1 - Test2 - team1 score)

Team name (Chelsea) 2 role: player2 can see the following pages (test1 - test2 - team2 score)

Role palyer1 should not be able to see the page team2 score, and role player2 should also not able
to see the page team1 score.

Structure of my website:

Team Valencia
   - role player / coach

Team Barcelona
     role player / coach

Can somebody tell me how to manage this thank you.

Comment: I don't want to be the party-pooper here. But it sounds like quite the project you're trying to put together. Setting permissions are quite the hassle. Especially if the the permission-levels aren't in a linear hierarchy. It's like saying: "I have some scrap metal and a bunch of glue and want to build a rocket". So even though there might be ways where you could properly do it, then I would suggest that the proper answer to that question should be, to make you take an extra step back and reconsider your plan.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this using Pages and Custom Post Types.

For content that everyone can see, use regular WP Core Pages.

For restricted content, build custom post types with mapped custom capabilities. You can then assign a role to each user, such as "coach" who can see all the content including scores, "team1" that can see team 1 posts including scores, and "team2" that can see team 2 posts including scores.

You can start with this code for a custom post type and build out any other options you need on your site:

```
<?php
// Define custom capabilities for this post type.
$capabilities = array(
    'edit_post'              => 'edit_team1',
    'read_post'              => 'read_team1',
    'delete_post'            => 'delete_team1',
    'create_posts'           => 'create_team1',
    'delete_posts'           => 'delete_team1',
    'delete_others_posts'    => 'delete_others_team1',
    'delete_private_posts'   => 'delete_private_team1',
    'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_team1',
    'edit_posts'             => 'edit_team1',
    'edit_others_posts'      => 'edit_others_team1',
    'edit_private_posts'     => 'edit_private_team1',
    'edit_published_posts'   => 'edit_published_team1',
    'publish_posts'          => 'publish_team1',
    'read_private_posts'     => 'read_private_team1',
);
$args         = array(
    // Map Meta Cap ensures your custom capabilities are used.
    'map_meta_cap'  => true,
    'show_in_rest'  => true,
    'public'        => true,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
    'capabilities'  => $capabilities,
);
register_post_type( 'team1', $args );
?>
```

Then you'll need a role with `read_team1` capabilities for anyone who can read the team 1 posts (which would include scores and anything else you're protecting).

```
<?php
add_role('team_one_player', 'Team One Player', array(
    // Let them read Team 1 CPTs.
    'read_team1' => true,
    // Also let them read Core content like Pages.
    'read' => true
    )
);
?>
```

And you'll probably want to grant Admins access to edit/delete. They don't have access by default so you have to grant it explicitly:

```
<?php
$admin = get_role('administrator');
$admin->add_cap('create_team_1');
$admin->add_cap('delete_team1');
$admin->add_cap('delete_others_team1');
$admin->add_cap('delete_private_team1');
$admin->add_cap('delete_published_team1');
$admin->add_cap('edit_team1');
$admin->add_cap('edit_others_team1');
$admin->add_cap('edit_private_team1');
$admin->add_cap('edit_published_team1');
$admin->add_cap('publish_team1');
$admin->add_cap('read_team1');
$admin->add_cap('read_private_team1');
?>
```

You'll just need to think carefully about how to structure the URLs in a way that makes sense for visitors, and you'll also need to think about UX. For example - are you going to have site navigation that links to all the pages, and have visitors without the proper capabilities get a "Sorry, you can't access that" message? Or, are you going to build conditional navigation that checks each link and only displays what the current user has the ability to view?

Alternatively, you could look into existing membership plugins. You could set up a "membership" for team 1 protected content, and a separate type of membership for team 2 protected content, potentially without coding.

Comment: Thank you for all your reactions, I installed the Ultimate membership plugin, and looked at options. I tried 2 options in the form function, the first of which was to create a new field for teams and the other is to duplicate the role field.

Comment: The firts option I create a new dropdown field named Teams, but it seems not working because I use  with the registration 2 user with the same role and different teams, they were both able to see the same pages. The second option was to duplicate the original Role field and put some conditions. the original field works fine but the duplicated field creates an account without assigning a role..

Comment: Assigning multiple roles tends to complicate things and some things may break. If you go the membership plugin route, you'll need to check with the creator for documentation and support. You could alternatively use User Role Manager instead, set up the roles and capabilities that way, as long as you've registered the CPTs with the right capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to WordPress, I would recommend using a plugin for this. [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-access-areas/) seems to allow you to restrict specific pages and posts to different roles. If you want to look for an alternative, try searching for "membership", "restrict access", or "control access".

Finally, [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) can help you create new user roles if you haven't already.